# Java wrapper for Soundtouch library

Tags: java, android, soundtouch

I haven't found any Java wrapper for Soundtouch apart from the one pointed out here: 
 [SoundTouch on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978228/soundtouch-on-android)

As far as I tried it, this wrapper is supposed to work only on Windows, but I'm working on `Linux`. I'm not that familiar with C++ development, and that's why I would like to keep my work on Java as much as possible.  
 Does anybody know any alternative to that wrapper?

Comment: If you're still looking I'm working on an Android wrapper for SoundTouch - https://github.com/svenoaks/SoundTouch-Android

Comment: @svenoaks - Will your project SoundTouch-Android work for any JavaSE application or is there stuff in there that makes it only work specifically on Android?